# Temp Table Errors in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two stored procedures: SP1 and SP2. They both contain the temp table #Temp, but the table structure is different between the two stored procedures.

There is a third stored procedure, SP3 called from both SP1 and SP2 and it updates columns in #Temp.

SP3 is something like this:

```
if @CallingSP = SP1 
begin update #Temp
      set ColumnA= 'abc'
end

if @CallingSP = SP2 
begin update #Temp
      set ColumnB= 'xyz'
end
```

Now, column "ColumnA" exists only in SP1 and "ColumnB" only in SP2. So when I execute SP3 from SP1, I get an invalid column error for "ColumnB".

What I am currently doing to get around this is creating another set of stored procedures and execute them in SP3 like this:

```
if @CallingSP = SP1 
begin exec SP4
end

if @CallingSP = SP2 
begin exec SP5
end
```

Is there another work around that doesn't require me to create SP4 and SP5?

Comment: Don't use a temporary table.  Use a table variable . . . `declare temp table (. . . )`.

Comment: use sp_executesql and build query string to execute

Answer (score 0):

Your if you must share table between parent-child proc you would need to rename #temp tables in calling procedures to be unique names. Below is code for `Test1, Test2, Test3` procedures to replicate your issue. In SP `Test3` instead of updating same #temp table I changed it to udpate `#temp1` in first case and `#temp2` in second case.

```
ALTER PROC Test1
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @SP_Name SYSNAME = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp1
        CREATE TABLE #temp1 ( ColumnA VARCHAR(1) )
        INSERT INTO #temp1 VALUES ( 'C' );
        EXEC dbo.Test3 @pProcCalled = @SP_Name;
        SELECT * FROM #TEMP1
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp1
    END

GO
ALTER PROC Test2
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp2
        DECLARE @SP_Name SYSNAME = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
        CREATE TABLE #temp2 ( ColumnB VARCHAR(1) )
        INSERT INTO #temp2 VALUES ( 'C' ); 
        EXEC dbo.Test3 @pProcCalled = @SP_Name;
        SELECT * FROM #TEMP2
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp2
    END

GO

ALTER PROC Test3 ( @pProcCalled SYSNAME )
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
            IF @pProcCalled = 'Test1'
                    UPDATE #temp1 SET ColumnA = 'A'

            IF @pProcCalled = 'Test2'
                    UPDATE #temp2 SET ColumnB = 'B'
    END
```

Another alternative would be using `OUTPUT` parameters.